# botman io + laravel not continue conversations

Tags: php, laravel, chatbot, botman

I am trying to start a conversation in laravel 7 and botman 2 with telegram. All works fine as but unable to continue the conversations. When I am trying to answer any previous question of the conversation it assuming to start the new conversation and not asking the 2nd question of the conversation thread.

The telegram webhook url i set is :

```
/api/telegram-bot
```

My routes/api.php

```
Route::post('/telegram-bot', 'TelegramController@bot');
```

TelegramController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Template
use App\Channel;
use Config;

use BotMan\BotMan\BotMan;
use BotMan\BotMan\BotManFactory;
use BotMan\BotMan\Drivers\DriverManager;
use App\Conversations\BankingConversation;

class TelegramController extends Controller{
  public function bot(){
        $config = [
            "telegram" => [
               "token" => "{MY_BOT_TOKEN}",
               'conversation_cache_time' => 30
            ]
        ];
        DriverManager::loadDriver(\BotMan\Drivers\Telegram\TelegramDriver::class);
        $botman = BotManFactory::create($config);
        
         
        $botman->hears('(hi|hello|start)', function (BotMan $bot) {
            $bot->startConversation(new BankingConversation , \BotMan\Drivers\Telegram\TelegramDriver::class );
        });

        $botman->fallback(function($bot) {
            $bot->reply('Sorry, I did not understand you. Just type start to continue.');
        });

        $botman->listen();
    }
}
```

and finally the BankingConversation

```
<?php

namespace App\Conversations;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Incoming\Answer;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Question;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Actions\Button;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation;

class BankingConversation extends Conversation
{

    protected $fullname;

    protected $email;

    public function askFullname()
    {
        $welcome = 'Hey '; 

        $this->ask($welcome.' What is your name ?', function(Answer $answer) {
            // Save result
            $this->fullname = $answer->getText();

            $this->say('Nice to meet you '.$this->fullname);
            $this->askEmail();
        });
    }

    public function askEmail()
    {
        $this->ask('One more thing - what is your email?', function(Answer $answer) {
            // Save result
            $this->email = $answer->getText();

            $this->say('Great - that is all we need, '.$this->firstname);
        });
    }

    public function run()
    {
        // This will be called immediately
        $this->askFullname();
    }
}
```

Whenever is am typing hi/hello/start  it's asking me first question of conversation "Hey What is your name ?"

But after replying to the question it's going to fallback and returning "Sorry, I did not understand you. Just type start to continue."

What is the mistake i am doing here ?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the cache driver.

update section of your code.

DriverManager::loadDriver(\BotMan\Drivers\Telegram\TelegramDriver::class);

$botman = BotManFactory::create($config, new \BotMan\BotMan\Cache\LaravelCache());

Botman uses cache to maintain the conversation.